# Self-Signed Certificate and IIS 6.0, How to generate a Client Certificate

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, iis-6

I am looking at generating a self-signed certificate, and only allow users who has client certificate installed on my web server. I am using IIS 6.0 with selfSSL to generate my .pfx web server certificate.
i was looking at this atricle http://www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=11&page=3 and it mentions about installing Client Certificate on Client Machine. How do i generate a Client certificate? do i use SelfSSL as well?
if i use SelfSSL do i Use

```
selfssl.exe /N:CN=ClientName /K:1024 /V:7 /S:1 /P:443
```

OR DO i install the same certificate installed on web server?

Comment: Cross posted http://serverfault.com/questions/288377/self-signed-certificate-and-iis-6-0-how-to-generate-a-client-certificate